# Applying a pop-up / lightbox to an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got this script which fetches stuff from a JSON. Onclick of the thumbnail, it opens up an `iframe` next to it. Well I want the `iframe` to pop out and make the background darker ( you know the drill ). How can I do that?

```
    $(function() {
    var i=0;
    var twitchApi = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams";
    var twitchData;
    $.getJSON(twitchApi, function(json) {
        twitchData = json.streams;

        setData()
    });

    function setData(){
        var j = twitchData.length > (i + 9)  ? (i + 9) : twitchData.length;
        for (; i < j; i++) {
            var streamGame = twitchData[i].game;
            var streamThumb = twitchData[i].preview.medium;
            var streamVideo = twitchData[i].channel.name;
            var img = $('<img style="width: 250px; height: 250px;" src="' + streamThumb + '"/>')
            $('#twitch').append(img);
            img.click(function(){
            $('#twitch iframe').remove()
            $('#twitchframe').append( '<iframe frameborder="0" style="overflow:hidden; margin-left: 25px; width:400px; height:250px; position: fixed; top: 0; margin-top: 23.55%;" src="http://player.twitch.tv/?channel=' + streamVideo + '"></iframe>');
          });
        }
    }       

    $('#load').click(function() {
        setData();
    }); 
});
```

Comment: If you set me up with a basic fiddle, I can give you a hand :) - otherwise, can you add **basic** HTML markup for me to look at?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/b31ghbww/1/ There you go.

Comment: Ok I completely misunderstood what you needed. Will have a look through this again in the morning and see what I can find :)